# IndexError in DMOJ even though the code runs without error and returns the expected output

Tags: python

I was attempting [DMOJ ECOO '13 R1 P1](https://dmoj.ca/problem/ecoo13r1p1), where, based on the variables within my code, the output should (1) return the total number of numb_count, (2) return the difference between numb_count and serve_count and (3) return number, for each time the user input is "CLOSE".

The input specifications are:
(1) The first number
(2) Action commands of either TAKE, SERVE, CLOSE, or EOF

The code below runs without error and gives the correct output, however, when submitting to DMOJ, it returns IndexError. Could you please advise me on why this is so and what changes to the code I would need to make? Thank you!

```py
ticketing_list = str(input()) 
ticketing = ticketing_list.split(" ")

def sequence(action): 
    numb_count = 0
    serve_count = 0
    number = int(ticketing[0])
    i = 1
    while action != "EOF": 
        if action == "TAKE": 
            numb_count += 1
            if number < 999: 
                number += 1 
            else: 
                number = 1 
        elif action == "SERVE":
            serve_count += 1
        elif action == "CLOSE":
            print(numb_count, (numb_count- serve_count), number) #prints the output we need
            #might need to reset afterward
            numb_count = 0 
            serve_count = 0
        i += 1
        action = ticketing[i]

def main():
    i = 1
    action = ticketing[i]
    sequence(action)
    

main()
```